# Mysql join query in ruby having two conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

how would i write this SQL query in ruby:

```
Select Id,Name,Email,number
from Participants
INNER JOIN Winners
on Winner.participant_id = Participant.id && Winner.sweepstake_id = Participant.sweepstake_id
```

Participants and Winners have one to one relationship.
P.S : I don`t know whether this query is correct or not but hope you get the idea what i am trying to achive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Participant.joins("INNER JOIN Winner ON Winner.id = Participant.id AND Winner.sweepstake_id = Participant.sweepstake_id").select("participants.id, participants.name, participants.email, participants.number")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Participant.joins("inner join winners on winners.id = participants.id AND winners.sweepstake_id = participants.sweepstake_id ").select("participants.id, participants.name,participants.email,participants.number")
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

The convention for Rails is to have tables named `participants` and `winners` (for models `Participant` and `Winner`), and to also lowercase the column names. Its also strange to join onto two primary keys: one of those should be a foreign key. In any case, if we assume those naming changes, but keeping the join conditions the same, you can query this in ActiveRecord like so:

```
@participants = Participant.select(:id, :name, :email, :number)
  .joins("INNER JOIN winners ON winners.id = participants.id AND winners.sweepstakes_id = participants.sweepstakes_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:
    `Participant.joins(:winner).where(:sweepstake_id => params[:id]`)